# Getting an error using parameter in Verilog

Tags: verilog, test-bench

I’m new to using verilog for verifying memories. I’ve defined address width and data width in the testbench as parameters, and I’m trying like this below which is giving me an error:

```
parameter ADDRESS_WIDTH =9
```

And down below in the testbench somewhere, I’m calling tasks:

```
Read_mode(ADDRESS_WIDTH’134)
```

I’m getting an error with this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

`ADDRESS_WIDTH’134` produces a syntax error because it is illegal to use a parameter for a numeric literal size like that, and when you use the apostrophe, it must be followed by a base specifier (such as `h` for hexadecimal format).  Also, the apostrophe character in your question might be a problem depending on how you copy and paste it into an editor.

To pass a numeric literal to a `task`, it is not necessary to specify the bit width of the value because that can be accounted for when you declare the `task` input.  You can declare the input with the desired bit width, then pass the numeric value with just the base specifier, such as `'h134` for a hexadecimal value:

```
module tb;

parameter ADDRESS_WIDTH = 9;

task Read_mode (input [ADDRESS_WIDTH-1:0] addr);
    $displayh(addr);
endtask

initial begin
    Read_mode('h134);
    Read_mode(134);
    Read_mode('hfff);
end

endmodule
```

Prints:

```
134
086
1ff
```

Note that `134` (without the base) is a decimal value, and that values larger that 9 bits (`'hfff`) will be forced to 9 bits (`1ff`).

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 5.7.1 *Integer literal constants*.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a parameter there directly (welcome to verilog). In System Verilog it could be solved using a typedef:

```
  parameter ADDRESS_WIDTH = 9;
  typedef logic [ADDRESS_WIDTH-1:0] awdt_t;
  ...
  Read_mode(awdt_t'(134));
```

Otherwise, you can use a macro

```
  `define ADDRESS_WIDTH 9
  ...
  Read_mode(`ADDRESS_WIDTH'd134);
```